# Visual Studio 2012 - Coded UI Test can't find control in webpage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have a simple login/logout sequence, but the test fails all the time with the message:

The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties

It's come at the login process, when it should write the username. The generated code seems good, tried to debug step-by-step and the controls exist, but when it hit that part the test fails.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you do a recording or a manually scripted the code?

Comment: is it being played back in the same version of IE as it was recorded?

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to set focus on your text fields and add assertions. Drag the crosshair over the text fields and add them as assertions, then generate code.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you try hand coding. Coded UI API with VS2012 is very simple and clean to use.

Also, if the above doesn't work then can you add your html snippet and uimap designer code?